# Why does the runtime allow the assignment of an NSDictionary out of an array into an NSString variable?

Tags: objective-c, types, variable-assignment

Consider this code:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) 
    [array addObject:[[NSDictionary alloc]init]];
NSString *poisonedString = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

In this above snippet, I have an array and I am inserting some dictionary objects into this array. While all this is fine and dandy, when I get the dictionary object from the array and put it into an string object, it is not causing any cast exceptions! The program runs smoothly and then crashes only when we do dictionary operations on the `poisonedString`! Why is this so? Why doesn't the Objective-C runtime see the type mismatch and raise an exception at the assignment, when the dictionary object is put into `poisonedString`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective-C is **not** type-checked at runtime at all unless those checks are explicitly added. What is done at runtime is method lookup in response to a message, and in this the type of the target is not considered only whether the target has an matching method.

At compile time the Clang compiler does as much static type-checking of the Objective-C additions to C as it can to provide the programmer with warnings when types are incorrect. However the programmer can always bypass those warnings with little difficulty if they really wish to, but it is generally ill-advised to do so.

Whenever the type of something is "lost", e.g. when it is put into a collection which allows for any type of object and later extracted, then the compiler cannot provide any meaningful help. It is up to the programmer to add code to check the actual runtime type and then cast the value to the determined type. While the cast itself does nothing at runtime at compile it informs the compiler of the determined type and that allows it to do better type checking and produce better warnings.

You test the type of something with the method `isKindOfClass`, so the outline template is:

```
id someVar = ...
if ( [someVar isKindOfClass:[SpecificType class]] )
{
   SpecificType *typeKnownVar = (SpecificType *)someVar;
   // now use typeKnownVar and compiler will do static checking where possible
}
else
{
   // deal with someVar not being of SpecificType
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, NSArray supports inserting any type of object into it. If you look at the documentation you can see a generic (id) object is returned when using *objectAtIndex*:

```
 - (id)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

With that in mind you can't expect the compiler to know ahead of time what type your object is when you get it from the array.

Comment: Okayy. Compiler cannot. I am not expecting the compiler to give me warnings/errors. But, what about runtime? Shouldn't the app just crash?

Comment: You did say it crashed, didn't you?

Comment: The type of the _variable_ does not really exist at runtime, @codingVoldemort. Variable types are only for the compiler. This is the same as C.

Comment: @JoshCaswell That makes a lot of sense!

Comment: I beg to differ, "The program runs smoothly and crashes when..." ;)

Comment: Check my answer if you want to understand it better

Comment: Crashes when we do dictionary operations on them.
Why doesn't the Objective-C runtime crash the program, when we put the Dictionary object in the String? I should have articulated it better. :)

Comment: As an additional note, @codingVoldemort, `id` is the "any object" type. I assume there's a similar type in Java, though I don't know what it would be. Even if the runtime were to do typechecking, it wouldn't be possible for it to raise an exception for an assignment of an `id` to any other object type -- that would negate the meaning of `id`.

Comment: You're not "putting the dictionary object in string", your referencing a pointer.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - compilers can and do add runtime checks when "up casting", such as assigning a general type such as `id` to a more specific one such as `NSString`, and this in no way "negates the meaning" of the general type. The point here is that Objective-C with its dynamic type system does not do such runtime checks, the programmer must add then (`isKindOfClass` etc.) if needed.

Comment: You're right, @CRD, I just meant that this could not be an _error_, warranting either compilation failure or a runtime exception.

Answer (score 1):

Because first of all you are not casting :) I can't see any cast, and second of all, welcome to Objective-C, this is what they call a Dynamic Language, and you can read more here
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html

Now back to your code, the arrays are not generic so you can add whatever items of whatever classes you want in the same array and when you get the item, you don't need to cast it, the compiler trusts you :D now if you try to send a message (or as you named it do some operations), it'll throw a runtime exception, so simply if you are in the situation where you don't know if it's an NSString or an NSDictionary, just use the below code to check the type of the object.

```
if ([array[0] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    // Do whatever you want
}
else if ([array[0] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    // Also do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Note that a cast does nothing at runtime and at compile time in Objective-C an "up cast" is a "trust me" from the programmer. To check the type at runtime you must use `isKindOfClass` (or similar) as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

in NSArray class reference the documentation present that the return of ObjectAtIndex is an id

objectAtIndex:
Returns the object located at the specified index.

```
- (id)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

It is not possible to the compiler to know the type of object when your pointer is an id. It's normal that dump at executing time and not at compiling time.